# Aligning two lists in python

Tags: python, list

I have a two Lists  one with truth values and other containing experimental results and their associated scores.

```
truth = [6, 8, 7, 10]
experiment = [(6, 5), (4, 3), (2, 4), (11, 6), (7, 4)]
```

I want to align my experiment and truth values such that maximum truth value align

```
        [6, 8, 7, 10]
        [6, missing, 7, missing]
```

Now I'd like to assign value to missing from the from among subsequences which are not aligned.

Here we chose 11 from among `(4, 3), (2, 4), (11, 6)` since it has the highest score. 
The last missing value is assigned `0` because no element lies beyond `(7, 4)`

```
truth = [6, 8, 7, 10]
exp  =  [6, 11, 7, 0]   # Zero because 7 is the last element of experiment subsequence.
```

I was looking in `difflib` library but didn't understand much. 
How should I go about this?

Comment: I understand the first result you're looking for but not the second.  You need to give us a little more detail, perhaps even some example code.

Comment: @KronoS I was thinking about using set operations for this but I am not sure if that's the correct approach

Comment: I'm talking about fundamentally here.  How do you get the `[6, 11, 7, 0]`?  I understand the `[6, NaN, 7, NaN]` though I don't think that tells you much.  What is your overall end goal here?

Comment: I mean for the missing values I'd like to substitute the subsequence with the value that has the highest likelihood. Here a value is missing between 6 and 7. I'll substitute 11 because it has the the maximum score among the values between 6 and 7

Comment: @KronoS How should I solve the first part of problem? Could you give me some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, you can do something like this:

```
truth = [6, 8, 7, 10]
experiment = [(6, 5), (4, 3), (2, 4), (11, 6), (7, 4)]

def prepare(exp):
    keys = [i for i, j in exp]
    def select(v):
        return v if v in keys else None
    return select

select = prepare(experiment)

exp = [select(i) for i in truth]

# exp will be [6, None, 7, None]
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part could be done with a simple list comprehension:

```
truth = [6, 8, 7, 10]
experiment = [(6, 5), (4, 3), (2, 4), (11, 6), (7, 4)]
res1 = [x if x in dict(experiment) else None for x in truth]
```

... or if you prefer lambda functions:

```
truth = [6, 8, 7, 10]
experiment = [(6, 5), (4, 3), (2, 4), (11, 6), (7, 4)]
res1 = map(lambda x: x if x in dict(experiment) else None, truth)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you'll never have two or more missing values next to each other, you can use:

```
truth = [6, 8, 7, 10]
experiment = [(6, 5), (4, 3), (2, 4), (11, 6), (7, 4)]

exp_list = [x[0] for x in experiment] #[6, 4, 2, 11, 7]

# Part one.
exp = [t if t in exp_list else None for t in truth] #[6, None, 7, None]

# Part two.
for i, t in enumerate(exp):
    if t == None:
        # Get index of previous and next truth values for missing values.
        i_prev = exp_list.index(exp[i-1]) if i else 0
        i_next = exp_list.index(exp[i+1]) if i < len(exp)-1 else len(exp_list)
        # Pick the largest value between them or 0 if no values are there.
        values_between = exp_list[slice(i_prev + 1, i_next)]
        exp[i] = max(values_between) if values_between else 0

print exp #[6, 11, 7, 0]
```

Comment: Well actually there could be missing values next to each. I could probably experiment with randomly selecting values from experiment. Thanks anyway :)